# Swift What's the performance difference between static stored property and static computed property?

Tags: swift

What's the performance difference between static stored property and static computed property?
When the full module optimization is turned on, are they effectively the same to the compiler?

For example, For a class marked as final.

```swift
final class DefaultsKeys {
    static let aStoredKey = "createdAt"
    static var aComputedKey: String { "createdAt" }
}
```

Comment: If you don't compute a value, you should not use computed propery. Instead use stored property.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post.

Comment: As per the discussion in the swift forum answered by "curk", who demonstrated that with compiler optimization, there is no difference for the above example. <https://forums.swift.org/t/static-computed-property-vs-static-let-constant/20968/3>. Therefore, this question is closed.